# AES 256 encryption PHP with Padding

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I got the following requirements for the encryption for the API i am currently trying to access:

- PKCS7 padding method
- CBC encryption mode
- AES key size 256, block size 128

Everytime i submit to the API with the encryption, there seems to be something wrong with the API (unfortunately no error is produced).

```
$Data = "GOOD!";
$aesKey = "1234567812345678";

$EncryptedData = encrypt($aesKey,$Data);
$DecryptedData = decrypt($aesKey,$EncryptedData);

echo "Orignal Data : ". $Data;
echo "<br/>";
echo "After encryption = ". $EncryptedData;
echo "<br/>";
echo "After decryption = " .$DecryptedData;

function encrypt($aesKey, $dataToEncrypt) {
    $output = false;
    $iv = '{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{';
    $output = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-128-CBC', $aesKey,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);
    return $output;
}

function decrypt($aesKey, $dataTodecrypt) {
    $output = false;
    $iv = '{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{';
    $dataTodecrypt = base64_decode ($dataTodecrypt);
    $dataTodecrypt = $output = openssl_decrypt($dataTodecrypt, 'AES-128-CBC',
    $aesKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $output;
}
```

Questions:

- What exactly is PKCS7 padding method and can be implemented with php?
- AES 256 is fine but what exactly does block size mean?
- What exactly does IV do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> AES 256 is fine but what exactly does block size mean?

AES has a fixed block size of 128 bit. A block cipher only works on *one* block of a specific size. A mode operation extends a block cipher with the ability to work on multiple blocks and a padding enables it to work on plaintexts that are not a multiple of the block size.

*AES-128-CBC* means AES with key size of 128 bit and the CBC mode of operation. If you want to use AES-256, then you need to tell OpenSSL that: *AES-256-CBC*. Additionally, you need to use a key that is actually 256 bit long. Your current key is only 128 bit long.

> What exactly is PKCS7 padding method and can be implemented with php?

`openssl_encrypt()` already does PKCS#7 padding for you and `openssl_decrypt()` removes it for you.

> What exactly does IV do?

A random IV randomizes the ciphertext which means that encrypting the same plaintext with the same key, but a different IV produces a different ciphertext which is indistinguishable from random noise or other the same encryption with a different IV. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) has a good description what this actually does.

Keep in mind that an IV must be randomly generated for each iteration. Otherwise, an attacker who observes only the ciphertext may discover that you encrypted the same plaintext multiple times.

---

Keep in mind that an AES key is supposed to be quite noisy with high entropy. "12345..." looks more like a password. If you want to use passwords, then you need to derive a key from that password. PBKDF2 is a good idea with a random salt and a lot of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is PKCS7 padding method and can be implemented with php?

I am not really certain 'padding' is the phrase you mean here. While the PKCS#7 format does rely on [padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-10.3), the example you provide has absolutely nothing to do with [asymmetric encryption](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/asymmetric-cryptography) and the [ASN.1](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) format for the [PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) messaging syntax mentioned.

> AES 256 is fine but what exactly does block size mean?

[Block size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography)) is the bit size an encryption cipher, like [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), operates on per permutation.

> What exactly does IV do?

An IV is short for [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) or for some symmetric encryption cipher implementations it can also be referred to as an [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Both are used to help strengthen the resulting cipher text. You can think of them as being similar to a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for a non-reversible hashing algorithm.

You should avoid re-using the same IV.

In regards to your example; the documentation for [openssl_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) states the following function usage:

```
string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )
```

Your encryption of the plain text looks accurate (while I would choose AES-256-GCM vs. AES-128-CBC as the algorithm, blocksize & mode):

```
$output = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-128-CBC', $aesKey,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

Without testing I am assuming you are getting a valid base64 encoded value.

The manual for the [openssl_decrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) method states the following usage:

```
string openssl_decrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )
```

While technically your implementation is correct; I would suggest the following (note the double assignment to *$dataTodecrypt = $output = openssl_decrypt()*):

```
$output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($dataTodecrypt), 'AES-128-CBC', $aesKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

Comment: If the other sides insists on using AES-256-CBC, `AES-128-CBC` is not ok ;-)

Comment: I think I address the choice of cipher, block size & mode in my answer. The use of CBC mode should not be used despite the increased blocksize; GCM mode provides authentication much like an HMAC.

Comment: "PKCS7 padding" is really only one very small part of PKCS#7, namely the symmetric padding. It really has nothing to do with asymmetric crypto. It's just a way to name this type of padding. See also [What is the difference between PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/13022)

Comment: @jas- Yes, you do address it. My point is: keylength 256, cbc, pkcs#7 are given as a requirement. There might be a reason for that. And as long as the OP cannot change the behaviour of the other side of the system, `AES-128-CBC` does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Nothing to do with asymmetric crypto? PKCS#7 according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652 (RFC-5652) uses asymmetric private/public keys pairs for message signing & validation.

Comment: @VolkerK, so in addition to the symmetric AES encryption there is a second private/public key signing & validation going on? The example makes no indication of that.

Comment: What do you mean? No, I do not imply that there's an additional assymetric step involved. What do you think that?

Comment: PKCS#7 also defines a [padding scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-10.3), When refering to `PKCS#7 padding` only this scheme is meant; regardless of whether the cipher is symteric or asymetric.

Comment: My answer addresses that as well. Do you have a point you are trying to make?

Comment: Yes,`$output = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-128-CBC'` is not ok given the requirements. And pkcs#7 padding matters. But it's the default for openssl_encrypt/aes anyway; just don't pass OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in the options parameter.

Comment: The padding that is commonly referred to as PKCS#7 padding is for example defined in [RFC2315 under chapter 10.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-10.3) and [RFC5652 under chapter 6.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3). It's such a trivial padding scheme that there is no dedicated name for it, so it is commonly referred to under a name where it was (first?) defined.